# homogeneous partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Is $$z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = y^2$$ equation homogeneous partial differential equation? Why??

$$z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + x^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = y^2$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{x^2}{z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{y^2}{z}$$

Is it because this PDE has $z$ or its partial derivative in each term?

Comment: Look under [homogeneous linear differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation).

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation given is not homogeneous.

The reason is quite simple, it is because $z(x,y)=0$ is not a solution to the PDE.